# python - how to get hierarchical class name

Tags: python

Is there a Python built-in way to get hierarchical class name `Base.Child.GrandKid` including all the parent classes similar to Java fully qualified class name?

```
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def class_id(cls):
        return cls.__qualname__
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, like="sushi", **kwargs)

class GrandKid(Child):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("hoge")
```

[PEP-3155](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/) `__qualname__` is for the internally nested class or function, and not **fully qualified** in terms of Java-like fully qualified name.

```
>>> class C:
...   def f(): pass
...   class D:
...     def g(): pass
...
>>> C.__qualname__
'C'
>>> C.f.__qualname__
'C.f'
>>> C.D.__qualname__
'C.D'
>>> C.D.g.__qualname__
'C.D.g'
```

## Update

As pointed out in the comments, it is not possible because of multiple inheritance. Leave the question as-is as there could be others like myself who assumed single inheritance in Python class.

Comment: Are you looking for `cls.mro()`?

Comment: It's worth noting that Python (unlike Java), supports multiple inheritance. So there isn't always a straight forward linearization of the parent classes, it takes some complex logic to sort it out. That's what the MRO is in Python. See [this documentation page](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) (which has, alas, had its ASCII art degrade a bit with website format changes over the years, but the important diagrams are still legible enough).

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that Java qualified names have nothing to do with inheritance: just like python qualified names.

Comment: Given that you can have multiple inheritance paths in python, you should be very clear about what output format you really want.